# How to sum up values in specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have column names saved in a list:

```
col_names = ["Col1","Col5",...]
```

Now I want to create a new column "Total" and for each row to sum up values of columns in `col_names`.

Should I use for loop or is there any function that does this job?

Comment: Where you want to ad this column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list of columns to index into a dataframe, and then sum across columns (axis=1):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (5,5)), columns=["Col{}".format(i) for i in range(1,6)])
>>> df
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0     4     7     3     5     6
1     2     1     3     7     9
2     4     7     8     0     1
3     0     4     1     1     3
4     5     8     1     5     7
>>> col_names = ["Col1", "Col5"]
>>> df[col_names]
   Col1  Col5
0     4     6
1     2     9
2     4     1
3     0     3
4     5     7
>>> df["Total"] = df[col_names].sum(axis=1)
>>> df
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Total
0     4     7     3     5     6     10
1     2     1     3     7     9     11
2     4     7     8     0     1      5
3     0     4     1     1     3      3
4     5     8     1     5     7     12
```

Comment: 2 mins, that's insanely quick I didn't even type "import pandas as pd"

Comment: @KlausosKlausos axis=1 means only perform the sum along the columns, and axis=0 along the rows

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
m = [[1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    ]

new_n = []    
for c in m:
    new_n.append(c + [sum(c)])

print new_n
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 6], [4, 5, 6, 15], [7, 8, 9, 24]]
```